# SEO for news aggregation web site?

Tags: seo, scraper-sites

What is the best effective SEO strategy for a news aggregation website with no dedicated page for articles?

Just one simple big portal that contains a card per article with direct links to external sources.

Comment: What happens when you get too many articles to all fit on cards on one page?     Do news stories just fall off the site?

Comment: we are planning a timeline scrolling system (today, yesterday....)

Answer (score 1):

What about a dedicated page for the source? You could also add a community section for added engagement (plus maybe the ability to save articles?).

Just make sure you have all your SEO bases covered so to speak. Clean code/markup, optimized pages, no duplicate or thin content, social media profiles and backlinks (can't forget the backlinks).

Comment: We did the choice to have no dedicated pages. One click to get the source page with full new experience from origin website seems better.